# Wrong dependency tree

Tags: apt

I'm trying to update my apt-get but I got the following error messages:

```
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/nvidia-340/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/nvidia/alternate-install-present.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory
```

I found out that now I don't have `/usr/lib/nvidia/` directory (I have `/usr/lib/nvidia-340/`). Recently I've been doing some manipulations with drivers and as far as I understand it, the problem is that I deleted something in an incorrect way, so that it left a trace in the dependency tree. How can I detect the unnecessary branches in the tree and delete it. Or, if I get it wrong, how to fix that? Here's the full log:

```
maxim@maximus:~$ sudo apt-get -V upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/nvidia-340/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/nvidia/alternate-install-present.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                   dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64:
 libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64 depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of filezilla:
 filezilla depends on libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1); however:
  Package libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package filezilla (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity:
 unity depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dev:
 libgl1-mesa-dev depends on libgl1-mesa-glx (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2); however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64
 filezilla
 unity
 libgl1-mesa-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```